# Dynamic event works more than once in WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a KeyDown event to the TextBoxes that I added dynamically in a WPF project. I expect this event to run once for any TextBox. However, when I press any key, this event works for the number of TextBox. How can I stop this event from running n-1 extra?

**Dynamic Event Definition**

```
        TextBox addTB = new TextBox();
        addTB.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        addTB.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        addTB.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gainsboro);
        addTB.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        addTB.AcceptsReturn = true;
        addTB.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        addTB.FontSize = 13;
        addTB.Text = toDo.toDo;
        addTB.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(64, 64, 64));
        addTB.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        addTB.Padding = new Thickness(2, 0, 10, 2);
        AddHandler(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(addedText_Changed));
        //AddHandler(TextBox.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(addedText_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus));
        AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(addedText_PreviewKeyDown));
        addTB.Tag = toDo.id;
```

**Event**

```
private void addedText_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Source is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox keyDownText = e.Source as TextBox;
            if (keyDownText.IsFocused)
            {
                if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Down))
                {                        
                    e.Handled = true;
                    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(mainWindow))
                    {
                        if (tb.Name != "textBox_toDo")
                        {
                            if (tb.Tag != null)
                            {
                                if ((int)tb.Tag > (int)keyDownText.Tag)
                                {
                                    tb.Focus();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                                    {
                                        tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Up))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(mainWindow).Reverse())
                    {
                        if (tb.Name != "textBox_toDo")
                        {
                            if (tb.Tag != null)
                            {
                                if ((int)tb.Tag < (int)keyDownText.Tag)
                                {
                                    tb.Focus();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                                    {

                                        tb.CaretIndex = tb.Text.Length;
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                                if ((int)tb.Tag == appData.toDoList.OrderBy(x => x.id).First().id)
                                {
                                    textBox_toDo.Focus();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_toDo.Text))
                                    {

                                        textBox_toDo.CaretIndex = textBox_toDo.Text.Length;
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return;

                }
                else if (e.Key.Equals(Key.F4))
                {                        
                    foreach (Image image in FindVisualChildren<Image>(mainWindow).Reverse())
                    {
                        if (image.Tag != null)
                        {
                            if (image.Name == "image_status" + keyDownText.Tag.ToString())
                            {
                                changeStatus(image);

                                //MouseButtonEventArgs ex = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left);
                                //ex.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent;

                                //image.RaiseEvent(ex);

                                return;
                                // Or
                                // InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I suggest you use the && operator to reduce nesting? Also, you could design other methods that would reduce repetition in your code, greatly.

Comment: Thank you four your suggestion. I applied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this ,

```
AddHandler(TextBox.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(addedText_PreviewKeyDown));
```

try adding direct handler,

```
 addTB.PreviewkeyDown += addTB_PreviewkeyDown;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AddHandler(addTB.TextChangedEvent , new TextChangedEventHandler(addedText_Changed));
AddHandler(addTB.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(addedText_PreviewKeyDown));
```

Looks like every time you create a text box, you register the event handlers for the text box class and not the text box object (addTB in your case) itself, so you have multiple registrations for each text box.

Comment: How can I miss this. Thanks a lot.